# How to get documents which is readable by user on Firestore Cloud depends on rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I have a basic rule on my Firestore Cloud database. I want to give user cafes that user is in but i am always getting the error "Missing or insufficient permissions.". What is the thing that I miss?

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{db}/documents {    
    match /cafes{
        allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;

      match /{cafe}{
        allow read: if get(/databases/$(db)/documents/cafes/$(cafe)/participants/$(request.auth.uid)) != null;
            }
    }
  }
}
```

here is the code that i use to reach to documents

```
export class MyApp {
  private rootPage:any;
  // rootPage:any = HomePage;

  constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen, afAuth: AngularFireAuth, afs: AngularFirestore) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();

      afAuth.auth.onIdTokenChanged(user=>{
        if(user){
          console.log(user.uid)
          afs.collection('cafes').valueChanges().subscribe(console.log)
        } else {
          console.log('logged out')
        }
      })
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: You should also include the code you are using to try to read (and giving the errors).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the key sentences from the [docs on security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) is

> Every database request from a Cloud Firestore mobile/web client
>   library is evaluated against your security rules ***before*** reading or
>   writing any data.

and this should answer your question: You cannot query documents by their visibility for a specific user because this would require Firestore to read and evaluate every document.

If you read this rule

```
match /{cafe}{
    allow read: if get(/databases/$(db)/documents/cafes/$(cafe)/participants/$(request.auth.uid)) != null;
}
```

as "Allow every user to view a cafe document if it contains his user id in the participants list" it becomes clear that Firestore needs to read the document to answer the question.

What you can try is allow read on all cafe documents and then query for those "the user is in" with the implication that users can read the other cafes as well.

You should take a look at [this official guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/role-based-access) for a concept on role based access on Firestore documents.

**Update**

I want to be more precise on the statement "You cannot query documents by their visibility for a specific user because this would require Firestore to read and evaluate every document."

You cannot query for all documents and expect to get those visible to the requesting user (like you do in `afs.collection('cafes')`, i. e. security rules are not filters.

What you can do is qualify (add a where clause) your query to only include the documents visible to the user. Firestore will match the qualified query against your security rules and if both match, fetch the desired results.

Comment: @HalilTevfik I elaborated on the "cannot" sentence but you may have already taken that information from the linked docs.